# How to add the eventRender dynamically in fullcalendar after addEvents using Symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

Here is a snip of my code. Plain user-calender.js file. On Ajax call I am initiating fullCalendar

```
let calendarElement;
window.ZC_Calendar = {
  calendarElement: undefined,
  init: function () {
    this.calendarElement = new FullCalendar.Calendar(
      document.getElementById('userCalender'),
      {
        timezone: 'local',
        customButtons: {
            occupied: {
            text: 'Occupied',
            },
            onLeave: {
            text: 'On leave',
            },
            available: {
            text: 'Available',
            },
        },
        headerToolbar: {
            right: 'prev,next dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
            center: 'title',
            left: 'available occupied onLeave',
        },
        firstDay: 1,
        allDaySlot: true,
        navLinks: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        displayEventEnd: true,
        displayEventTime: true,
      }
    );
    this.calendarElement.render();
  },
};
```

Now initiating the calendar on some action:

```
.on('change', '#teamMembers', function (e) {
   if ($(this).val() > 0) {
       ZC_Calendar.init();
      self.userAvailabilityCalender(this);
   }
})
```

Here is final ajax call, which fetch the data from and load on calendar.
Here after the addEvent I want to show the tooltip of description portion

```
userAvailabilityCalender: function (input) {
        ZC_Calendar.calendarElement.removeAllEvents();
        $.ajax({
            url: Routing.generate('get_user_calender', {userId: $(input).val()}),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                for (let i = 0; i < response['events'].length; i++) {
                    ZC_Calendar.calendarElement.addEvent(response['events'][i]);
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Final output of calendar:
[image]

Comment: Sorry it's not really clear what your quesiton is. If you want to set something to happen when an event is rendered, you can set the appropriate options in fullCalendar's config when you initialise the calendar. If you're using v5 you can use one of the [event render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks), or for v4 you can use [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventRender). If you define any event rendering functionality, it will be executed automatically for every event which is shown on the calendar. You can use it to attach code to create tooltips etc.